# Decimals are being rounded in crystal reports and computing incorrectly

Tags: crystal-reports, sql-server-2012, report, decimal

Decimals are being rounded in crystal reports. The field(database field defined as float) Hours is being wrongly displayed in the crystal report. For example, 1.5 in the db is showing as 2.00, .75 shows as 1.00 and so on. There is also a field used to sum all the hours. That field is also picking the rounded values and summing incorrectly. I have formatted Hours as 1.00 and .01 in the formatting of crystal reports(for rounding & decimals). I also have the common tab(in format editor) as LN_Hours. Nothing seems to be working. I tried using x-2 formula with no luck.
Using crystal reports XI and SQL server MS 2012 and Visual studio 2003. Please throw some light on this situation! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error , finally figured it out! The float from the database was being converted to decimal and being shown on the crystal report. Someone forgot to define the decimal places! Its all fixed up and running as expected. Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In Crystal report 
1. "Right Click" on the field and go to Format Field
2. In Format Editor go to Number Tab and then select from the different available decimal formats.

It may be rounding because of rounding decimal places